# How to animate a knot tying and morphing into other knots?

Tags: animation, animate

I want to animate a transition between two (more later but just two for now) different types of knots, I was told it was almost mathematically impossible to do such a thing in After Effects, does anyone know what software and how I would go about doing something like this?

[image]

Screenshot attached shows rough sketch of two knots, imported from AI. I want the animation to just show one knot, morphing into the next.

Comment: If you draw them as a single SVG path you could morph them using something like GSAP's MorphSVG plugin. But that won't give you realistic results; not sure if you need that. The only real way to do realistic results would be to draw or photograph each step

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a 3d animation software

Comment: Again I know of no software that would give you realistic results without doing a frame by frame animation yourself